# MySQL adding value from previous row

Tags: mysql, cumulative-sum

I have a table with a single column. The column is like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
...
```

I want to create a query that will display another column that will have the previous value added to it. So:

```
1 1 ( 0 + 1 )
2 3 ( 1 + 2 )
3 5 ( 2 + 3 )
4 7 ( 3 + 4 )
5 9 ( 4 + 5 )
9 14 (5 + 9)
45 54 ( 9 + 45)
```

How would I construct a query to accomplish that?

Essentially, I just want the `difference` between `ROW[X]`, and `ROW[X-1]`.

Comment: nick i just deleted the answer because I didn't tested it and it shows different result from what you want. can you explain a little bit more or provide much better example. This is my previous code `SELECT  a.val, (@runtot := @runtot + a.val) AS rt
FROM    table1 a,(SELECT @runtot:=0) c`. Thanks.

Comment: i just want to get the previous row's value and add it to the current row's value and display it in a new column. thats it

Comment: i updated the example in my question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.val, (@runtot :=  a.val  + @runtot) AS rt, ( @runtot := a.val ) ne
FROM    Table1 a,(SELECT @runtot:=0) c
```

This seems to be working. I tried reinit the variable at each stage.
Try it out.

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8645d/1)

Comment: I actually came up with that just now. The only thing i cant do is return just the `rt`, not the `ne`.. this is a subquery

Comment: yea true. Thanx :) 
I am happy to get an upvote for the answer my first reputation :)

Answer (score -1):

TRY

```
SELECT  a.int, (@runtot :=  a.int  + a.int - 1) AS rt
FROM    test a,(SELECT @runtot:=0) c
```

ie

```
1 1 ( 0 + 1 )
2 3 ( 1 + 2 )
3 5 ( 2 + 3 )
4 7 ( 3 + 4 )
5 9 ( 4 + 5 )
```

this will result the output you shown

Comment: although this accomplishes what's in the example, in my actual scenario the numbers may skip which would miscalculate. that's why i need to record the last row's value. i should have been more explicit about that sorry